# Apache2 Mod_spamhaus Whitelist

Tags: apache-2.2, security, malware, spam, botnet

We are using Apache2 mod_spamhaus and many customers were banned using the "Post" method.
There is no way to deny mod_spamhaus ban continuously our customers making false positive or ban customers only cause their ip is on a range of banned ips?
What is the  syntax of the spamhaus.wl file? It's correct write the ips we want to whitelist like this on that file?

> example
>
> 122.0.0.1
>
> 127.0.0.2

N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to add the following to your spamhaus.wl file:

122.0.0.0/8

Read the background from TildalWave at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30224/mod-spamhaus-whitelist-example-to-allow-a-range-of-ips